# Find all stored procedures with particular starting name

Tags: sql, sybase

I have many stored procedures in my database. I have to transfer a few of them to a different server.

I need to find the procedures starting with "ABC".

How do I search all these stored procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.tables/html/tables/tables49.htm), this query should give you the procedures that start with "ABC":

```
SELECT o.name
FROM sysobjects AS o
INNER JOIN sysprocedures AS p ON o.id = p.id
WHERE o.name LIKE "ABC%"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

However it gave me error for 'Name' which I had to change it to 'name'.

Comment: @Aniruddha Thank you for letting me know.  I updated my answer to help people who read it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

a little tweak of Adam Wenger answer, that worked for me:

```
SELECT o.name
FROM sysobjects AS o
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES AS p ON o.name = p.SPECIFIC_NAME
WHERE o.name LIKE '%price%'
```

OR

```
SELECT o.name
FROM sysobjects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p ON o.id = p.object_id
WHERE o.name LIKE '%price%'
```

Answer (score 0):

No join necessary here and uses the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view (available since SQL Server 2005)

```
SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE 'ABC%'
ORDER BY SPECIFIC_NAME ASC
```